# how to build a list on the fly with condition, the functional way

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am still not good working with lists in Mathematica the functional way. Here is a small problem that I'd like to ask what is a good functional way to solve.

I have say the following list made up of points. Hence each element is coordinates (x,y) of one point.

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}
```

I'd like to traverse this list, and every time I find a point whose y-coordinate is say > 3.5, I want to generate a complex conjugate point of it. At the end, I want to return a list of the points generated.  So, in the above example, there are 2 points which will meet this condition. Hence the final list will have 5 points in it, the 3 original ones, and 2 complex conjugtes ones.

I tried this:

```
If[#[[2]] > 3.5, {#, {#[[1]], -#[[2]]}}, #] & /@ a
```

but I get this

```
{{1, 2}, {{3, 4}, {3, -4}}, {{5, 6}, {5, -6}}}
```

You see the extra {} in the middle, around the points where I had to add a complex conjugate point. I'd like the result to be like this:

```
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, -4}, {5, 6}, {5, -6}}
```

I tried inserting Flatten, but did not work, So, I find myself sometimes going back to my old procedural way, and using things like Table and Do loop like this:

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}
result = {};
Do[

 If[a[[i, 2]] > 3.5, 
   {
    AppendTo[result, a[[i]]]; AppendTo[result, {a[[i, 1]], -a[[i, 2]]}]
   }, 
   AppendTo[result, a[[i]]]
 ],
 {i, 1, Length[a]}
 ]
```

Which gives me what I want, but not functional solution, and I do not like it.

What would be the best functional way to solve such a list operation?

**update 1**

Using the same data above, let assume I want to make a calculation per each point as I traverse the list, and use this calculation in building the list.  Let assume I want to find the Norm of the point (position vector), and use that to build a list, whose each element will now be  {norm, point}. And follow the same logic as above.  Hence, the only difference is that I am making an extra calculation at each step.

This is what I did using the solution provided:

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}

If[#[[2]] > 3.5, 
   Unevaluated@Sequence[ {Norm[#], #}, {Norm[#], {#[[1]], -#[[2]]}}], 
   {Norm[#], #}
 ] & /@ a
```

Which gives what I want:

```
{    {Sqrt[5],{1,2}}, {5,{3,4}}, {5,{3,-4}}, {Sqrt[61],{5,6}}, {Sqrt[61],{5,-6}}   }
```

The only issue I have with this, is that I am duplicating the call to Norm[#] for the same point in 3 places. Is there a way to do this without this duplication of computation?

This is how I currently do the above, again, using my old procedural way:

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}
result = {};
Do[
 o = Norm[a[[i]]];
 If[a[[i, 2]] > 3.5, 
  {
   AppendTo[result, {o, a[[i]]}]; AppendTo[result, {o, {a[[i, 1]], -a[[i, 2]]}}]
  }, 
  AppendTo[result, {o, a[[i]]}]
 ],
 {i, 1, Length[a]}
]
```

And I get the same result as the functional way, but in the above, since I used a temporary variable, I am doing the calculation one time per point.

Is this a place for things like sow and reap? I really never understood well these 2 functions. If not, how would you do this in functional way?

thanks

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments and answers. If I can accept them all, I would. The more I learn about the 'functional' way to program and work with lists, the more I find it more powerful. I am going through a demo I am writing now, and changing some of my procedural code to be more 'functional' as I learn more, and I find the functional way much shorter and less error-prone. I just think it takes more skill and time to become good in functional programming compared to procedural, but it seems worth it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way is to use `Sequence`.

Just a minor modification to your solution:

```
If[#1[[2]] > 3.5, Unevaluated@Sequence[#1, {#1[[1]], -#1[[2]]}], #1] & /@ a
```

However, a plain `ReplaceAll` might be simpler:

```
a /. {x_, y_} /; y > 3.5 :> Sequence[{x, y}, {x, -y}]
```

This type of usage is the precise reason `Rule` and `RuleDelayed` have attribute `SequenceHold`.

**Answer to update 1**

I'd do it in two steps:

```
b = a /. {x_, y_} /; y > 3.5 :> Sequence[{x, y}, {x, -y}]
{Norm[#], #}& /@ b
```

In a real calculation there's a chance you'd want to use the norm separately, so a `Norm /@ b` might do

Comment: +1, cool. I actually tried Sequence there, but did it this way:   If[#[[2]] > 3.5, Sequence[{#, {#[[1]], #[[2]]}}], #] & /@ a   and it did not work either. I did not know this trick of Unevaluated@Sequence like this. I like your second solution also. Thanks.

Comment: I have a follow up on the same question, which I have been struggling with to do in functional way. Please see update 1.

Answer (score 10):

`Flatten` takens a second argument that specifies the depth to which to flatten.  Thus, you could also do the following.

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
Flatten[If[#[[2]] > 3.5, {#, {#[[1]], -#[[2]]}}, {#}] & /@ a, 1]
```

The most serious problem with your `Do` loop is the use of `AppendTo`.  This will be very slow if `result` grows long.  The standard way to deal with lists that grow as the result of a procedure like this is to use `Reap` and `Sow`.  In this example, you can do something like so.

```
new = Reap[
  Do[If[el[[2]] > 3.5, Sow[{el[[1]], -el[[2]]}]],
  {el, a}]][[2, 1]];
Join[a, new]
```

Comment: I actually tried Flatten[..,1], but I was off by one {}. This is what I tried: If[#[[2]] > 3.5, {#, {#[[1]], #[[2]]}}, #] & /@ a; Flatten[%, 1]; and did not work. I needed to add an extra {} around the last # above.  Did not see that. These {{{}}} can get one crazy :). Thanks for the answer and showing Reap and Sow.

Answer (score 10):

While Mathematica can simulate functional programming paradigms quite well, you might consider using Mathematica's native paradigm -- pattern matching:

```
a = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}

b = a /. p:{x_, y_ /; y > 3.5} :> Sequence[p, {x, -y}]
```

You can then further transform the result to include the `Norm`s:

```
c = Cases[b, p_ :> {Norm@p, p}]
```

There is no doubt that using `Sequence` to generate a very large list is not as efficient as, say, pre-allocating an array of the correct size and then updating it using element assignments.  However, I usually prefer clarity of expression over such micro-optimization unless said optimization is measured to be crucial to my application.

Comment: In Matlab one usually uses pre-allocation and assignment, but in Mathematica it's usually much easier and just as efficient to use `Sow` and `Reap`, as shown by Mark McClure.  Especially when you don't know the size you need beforehand (and thus would need to efficiently grow the array by doubling its size or something similar).

Comment: @Szabolcs I agree that Sow/Reap is often the best balance between expressiveness and efficiency.  In Mathematica, there are often many possible solutions to problems that only a stopwatch can tell apart from a performance standpoint.  Natuarally, imperative techniques often provide the greatest prospect for optimization.  The OP was looking for guidance to move away from imperative to functional techniques.  I guessed that the motivation was expressiveness, so the main concern of my response was to suggest looking beyond functional to pattern rewriting, the main Mathematica paradigm.

Answer (score 7):

To answer your edit, use `With` (or `Module`) if you're going to use something expensive more than once.

Here's my version of the problem in your edit:

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
Table[With[{n = Norm[x]}, 
  Unevaluated@Sequence[{n, x}, 
    If[x[[2]] > 3.5, {n, {1, -1} x}, Unevaluated@Sequence[]]]], 
 {x, a}]
```

The structure of the above could be modified for use in a `Map` or `ReplaceAll` version, but I think that `Table` is clearer in this case. The unevaluated sequences are a little annoying. You could instead use some undefined function `f` then replace `f` with `Sequence` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Mark's Sow/Reap code does not return the elements in the order requested.  This does:

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};

Reap[
  If[Sow[#][[2]] > 3.5, Sow[# {1, -1}]] & /@ a;
][[2, 1]]
```

Comment: @Verbeia hm... I suppose so.  I guess I am still not entirely comfortable with changing someone's post.  If you concur that this is a good change, I will make the edit and delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may use join with Apply(@@):

> Join @@ ((If[#[[2]] > 3.5, {#, {#[[1]], -#[[2]]}}, {#}]) & /@ a)